# Hapi - reply with HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm new to Hapi and Javascript and I'm trying to show a page in the browser. I have an main.html file that i want to be displayed as soons as we enter the first page, but with the code like it is I always get the error

```
"{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}"
```

How can I display an html file?

The js file:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });


server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.view('main.html');
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{name}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello, ' + encodeURIComponent(request.params.name) + '!');
    }
});

server.start(function () {
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up the view config for the server? In the [docs](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views) they say you require a view engine (like handlebars / swig).

If not maybe you could try serving a file with the absolute path

```
var path = require('path');

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file(path.join(__dirname, '../../../path/to/main.html'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hapi 9.x.x you need to load vision plugin to be able to use reply.view method.  See docs here
https://github.com/hapijs/vision

Answer (score 0):

hapi `9.0.0` and later require the [vision](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) for template rendering support. With vision, you’re decorating the `reply` interface with a `view` method that allows you to send HTML responses:

Your setup would look like this:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi')  
var Vision = require('vision')  
var Handlebars = require('handlebars')

// create new server instance
var server = new Hapi.Server()

// register vision to your server instance
server.register(Vision, function (err) {  
  if (err) {…}

  // configure template support   
  server.views({ // config here 
  })
})
```

And then you can reply HTML like this:

```
server.route({  
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    var data = { message: 'Hello from Future Studio' }
    reply.view('index', data)
  }
})
```

You can follow also follow this tutorial:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-render-views

Hope that helps!